# Strange red Block under Flutter TextField Widget

Tags: input, flutter

I'm working on a shopping list in one tab of my flutter app but under the Input field i always get and strange red block when the keyboard comes up (red block stays there until keyboard goes away)
[RedBlock which appears with keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrCTr.png)

Debug report which shows up after clicking into the field

```
Performing full restart...
Restarted app in 1.172ms.
D/ViewRootImpl@da3a8cd[MainActivity](28869): ViewPostImeInputStageprocessPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@da3a8cd[MainActivity](28869): ViewPostImeInputStageprocessPointer 1
I/flutter (28869): [{name: Lukas, id: 1, value: 32}, {name: Sophie, id: 2, value: 20}, {name: Peter, id: 3, value: 45}]
D/ViewRootImpl@da3a8cd[MainActivity](28869): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@da3a8cd[MainActivity](28869): ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
V/InputMethodManager(28869): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@b63ece2 nm : com.yourcompany.flutterapp ic=io.flutter.plugin.editing.InputConnectionAdaptor@484e873
I/InputMethodManager(28869): [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/InputTransport(28869): Input channel constructed: fd=101
D/InputTransport(28869): Input channel destroyed: fd=100
D/InputMethodManager(28869): ISS - flag : 0Pid : 28869 view : com.yourcompany.flutterapp
D/ViewRootImpl@da3a8cd[MainActivity](28869): MSG_RESIZED: frame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2220) ci=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 918) vi=Rect(0, 63 - 0, 918) or=1
D/ViewRootImpl@da3a8cd[MainActivity](28869): Relayout returned: oldFrame=[0,0][1080,2220] newFrame=[0,0][1080,2220] result=0x1 surface={isValid=true -887126016} surfaceGenerationChanged=false
```

Here you can see my code i have written:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:core';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';


class ShoppingBasket extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  ShoppingBasketState createState() => new ShoppingBasketState();
}

class ShoppingBasketState extends State<ShoppingBasket> {

  Directory documentsDirectory;
  String dirPath;
  Database database;
  List<Map> listRecords;
  Widget listView;

  final TextEditingController _controller1 = new TextEditingController(); // name field
  final TextEditingController _controller2 = new TextEditingController(); // value field

  @override
  void initState() {
    listView = beforeDataFetchIsFinished();
    getPathAndCheckForDbAndPrepareListView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          inputFieldCard(),
          listView,   //--> List view gets after all data was fetched here
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//View Build ------------------------------------------------------------------------

  /// Set the listview variable with an CircularPorgressIndicator.
  /// gets overriden if the real listview has finished.
  Widget beforeDataFetchIsFinished() {
    return new Container(
      margin: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 30.0, 0.0, 0.0),
      child: new Center(
        child: new CircularProgressIndicator(
          strokeWidth: 2.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  /// The Inputfield card in one methode.
  /// Returns the InputCard as one widget.
  Widget inputFieldCard() {
    return new Container(
      child: new Card(
        child: new Container(
            child: new Column(
              children: <Widget>[

                new Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Container(
                      width: 150.0,
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                      child: new TextField(
                        controller: _controller1,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Name...',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Container(
                      width: 150.0,
                      padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 20.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                      child: new TextField(
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        controller: _controller2,
                        decoration: new InputDecoration(
                          hintText: 'Value...',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                new Container(
                  padding: new EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0),
                  child: new RaisedButton(

                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: new Text('Insert Data', style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                    onPressed: () {
                      insertToDb(_controller1.text, _controller2.text);
                      _controller1.clear();
                      _controller2.clear();
                    },
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            )
        ),
      ), //top card end
    );
  }

  /// the CircularProgressIndicator gets overiden if this
  /// methode gets all its data --> then rerender.
  Widget injectListViewAfterAllDataIsFetched() {
    return new Card(
      child: new Container(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,       //<-- Necessary because Listveiw inside Column
          itemCount: listRecords == null ? 0 : listRecords.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(listRecords[index]['name']),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Data-Base Operations --------------------------------------------------------------

  /// Start up --> Open db and fetching data when complete
  /// start render engine again.
  Future<bool> getPathAndCheckForDbAndPrepareListView() async {
    documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dirPath = documentsDirectory.path;

    List content = documentsDirectory.listSync();
    final File file = new File(dirPath + '/myDataBase.db');
    if(!content.contains(file)) {                                                    //Check if db exists
      await createDbIfNotExists(file);                                               //if not create it
    }

    print(await getRecords());
    listRecords = await getRecords();
    print(listRecords);

    setState(() {
      listView = injectListViewAfterAllDataIsFetched();
    });

    return true;
  }

  /// Inserting data into the data base.
  /// @return true.
  Future<bool> insertToDb(String name, String value) async {
    if(name != '' && value != '') {
      var valueSql = int.parse(value);
      String sql = 'INSERT INTO Test(name, value) VALUES("$name", $valueSql)';
      await database.inTransaction(() async {
        await database.rawInsert(sql);
      });
      listRecords = await getRecords();

      setState(() {
        listView = injectListViewAfterAllDataIsFetched();
      });
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  /// Gives the whole Db back.
  /// @return Map with all records.
  Future<List<Map>> getRecords() async {
    return await database.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Test');
  }

  /// Creating the given File (should be an .db file).
  /// @param file Gives the file (.db) which gets created.
  /// @return true.
  Future<bool> createDbIfNotExists(File file) async {
    database = await openDatabase(file.path, version: 1,
      onCreate: (Database db, int version) async {
        await db.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE Test (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, value INTEGER)");
      });
    return true;
  }




}
```

Does someone of you understand why this is showing up? And have an smart Solution to fix it?

Edit: Some Photos which show my Keyboard with shortcuts and without them

[image: Without Keyboard Shortcuts]
[image: With Keyboard Shortcuts]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same problem. Just set resizeToAvoidBottomPadding false in you scaffold and it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The red bar indicates that the content of one of your containers or columns are bigger, than allowed by their parent. I cant reproduce this issue on iOS or Android. Also, why is the raised button not displayed in your screenshot?

Comment: The RaisedButton isn't visible because of the red block. Also i gave you that exact code that i used.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not able to reproduce your problem... :|

Comment: :( I updated the whole code with that what i have written the last hours (still the red block issue) maybe someone can reproduce the issue. But Note this is code is one tab in my app and the tapp drawer is handeld in an different file

Comment: I found something in the docu: 

"Why is my row turning red?
If the contents of the row overflow, meaning that together they are wider than the row, then the row runs out of space to give its Expanded and Flexible children, and reports this by drawing a red warning box on the edge that is overflowing." 

Can you try wrapping your widgets in an Expanded? I don't know which of your widgets is causing this issue so you will have to experiment a little ;)

Comment: Its strange because if i tap into the textfield ther shouldn't be any resizing. It's like the keyboard is resizing something. Does the keyboard just overlaping or is it formatting something?

Comment: I noticed some more Strange behavior when i turn off my Keyboard shortcuts the red block gets smaller. I also made an new tab with just the Textfield and the Button in an column. There i have a very small red block with turned on keyboard shortcuts and without these the red block isn't anymore. I added some Photos there you can see what i mean